# SQL nested SELECT inside INSERT

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to insert value that i get with SELECT to table, but i have no idea how to format it so it's work. When i try the SELECT statement alone, it returns value that i want, but when its nested it returns 0 which it shouldn't. I tried wrapping it in `""   ''` but it doesn't work.

```
INSERT
INTO
  brand(brand_id,
  NAME,
  cat_id)
VALUES(
  NULL,
  "value",
  (
  SELECT
    cat_id
  FROM
    category
  WHERE
    cat_id = 'number'
)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `insert . . . select`.  Leave out the `values`:

```
INSERT INTO brand(brand_id, NAME, cat_id)
  SELECT NULL, 'value', cat_id
  FROM category
  WHERE cat_id = 'number';
```

Three comments:

- If `number` is really a number, then don't use quotes.
- This is slightly different from your version because it will insert no rows if there are no matches.
- If the subquery returns exactly one row, then your version should work.

Comment: It works, thanks. The select statement confused me a bit because i didn't know i can put values that are not even in table there.